# Stop Code Execution After Calling UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

How can I stop code execution after showing UIAlertView until user pressed on the OK button? If that's a problem, what are the workarounds?

Comment: That depends, specifically what code is executing that you want to stop?

Comment: I'm building a simple game where I use delegation to notify the user that something happened. I don't use threads in the project, if that an issue. I show the alert in the main UIViewController.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up using this:

...

```
[alert show];

while ((!alert.hidden) && (alert.superview != nil))
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] limitDateForMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't want to execute the code that is written just after your [alertview show] method.  To implement this add those lines of code to a method and call that method  in the following delegate of UIAlertView.

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if(buttonIndex == OKButtonIndex)
       {
         // Issue a call to a method you have created that encapsulates the 
         // code you want to execute upon a successful tap.
         // [self thingsToDoUponAlertConfirmation];
       }

    }
```

Now, if you are going to have more than one UIAlertView within your class, you'll want to make sure that you can easily handle each UIAlertView.  You can do this with an NSEnum and a tag setting on UIAlertView.

If you have three alerts, at the top of your class declare an NSEnum before your @interface like so:

```
 // alert codes for alertViewDelegate // AZ 09222014
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AlertTypes)
{
    UserConfirmationAlert = 1, // these are all the names of each alert
    BadURLAlert,
    InvalidChoiceAlert
};
```

Then, right before your [alert show], set the tag of the alert to be the displayed.

```
myAlert.tag = UserConfirmationAlert;
```

Then in your UIAlertDelegate, you can perform the desired method within a switch/case like so:

```
// Alert handling code
#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate - What to do when a dialog is dismissed.
// We are only handling one button alerts here.  Add a check for the buttonIndex == 1
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch (alertView.tag) {
        case UserConfirmationAlert:
            [self UserConfirmationAlertSuccessPart2];
            alertView.tag = 0;
            break;

        case BadURLAlert:
            [self BadURLAlertAlertSuccessPart2];
            alertView.tag = 0;
            break;

        case InvalidChoiceAlert:
            [self InvalidChoiceAlertAlertSuccessPart2];
            alertView.tag = 0;
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"No tag identifier set for the alert which was trapped.");
            break;
    }
}
```